# How to avoid checking particular 'linq where clause' if that value is "any"?

Tags: c#, linq

I have below LINQ query:

```
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.Duration == durationCr_Filter 
    && f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter 
    && f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter 
    && f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter 
    && f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter).ToList();
```

in above query sometime i get some parameters values like value=="any". in that situation i want to avoid checking only that parameter. Can anyone please guide me how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below might work if you want to skip the condition if the filter is "any"

```
 SailingMain_Details =
                SailingMain_Details.Where(f => (durationCr_Filter != "any" ? f.Duration == durationCr_Filter : true)
                                                              && (depPortCr_Filter != "any" ? f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter : true)
                                                              && (cruShipCr_Filter != "any" ? f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter : true)
                                                              && (cruLineCr_Filter != "any" ? f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter : true)
                                                              && (destinationCr_Filter != "any" ? f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter : true)).ToList();
```

Comment: If the value does not matter it is far better to leave it out of the resulting query than include the value checks to the query. Please see Daniel A Sathis Kumar's response (but remove the extra .ToList() calls)

Comment: @JanneMatikainen we are just skipping the value check by adding true to the condition , if the filter is "any"

Comment: It will still include something like 1 == 1  to the sql query to get the true part working, far batter solution is not to add filter statements to the IQueryable that you are not gonna use.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want let me show you by example with `DeparturePortID`. Let's say "any" valu eis `-1`:

```
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details
  .Where(f => 
    f.Duration == durationCr_Filter 
    && (depPortCr_Filter == -1 || f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter)
    && f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter 
    && f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter 
    && f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter)
  .ToList();
```

Here, if `depPortCr_Filter` is `-1`, then `(depPortCr_Filter == -1 || f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter)` evaluates to `true`, independently of `f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Apply every filter on separate. example

```
if(durationCr_Filter.toUpper() != "ANY")
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.Duration == durationCr_Filter);

if(depPortCr_Filter.toUpper() != "ANY")
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter);

if(cruLineCr_Filter.toUpper() != "ANY")
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter);

if(cruShipCr_Filter.toUpper() != "ANY")
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter);

if(destinationCr_Filter.toUpper() != "ANY")
SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter);
```

Comment: You don't want to use .ToList() for every query, keep working with the IQueryable as long as you can and only finally return the materialized query results, in your case calling .ToList() for each condition would cause a database query (if the SailingMain_Details is for instance entity framework dbset)

Answer (score 0):

I assume here some parameter means it can be for any of those 5 params so you can try something like

```
 SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => (f.Duration == durationCr_Filter || durationCr_Filter == "any") 
 && (f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter ||  depPortCr_Filter == "any")  &&
 (f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter || cruLineCr_Filter == "any")  && (f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter || cruShipCr_Filter == "any")  &&
 (f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter || destinationCr_Filter == "any") ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
     if (SailingMain_Details.Any(x => x.value == "any"))
            {
// avoid the check here
                SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.Duration == durationCr_Filter && f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter && f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter && f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter && f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                SailingMain_Details = SailingMain_Details.Where(f => f.Duration == durationCr_Filter && f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter && f.CruiseLine == cruLineCr_Filter && f.ShipName == cruShipCr_Filter && f.DestinationCr == destinationCr_Filter).ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g avoid checking means basically it shall return true by default.  for one item see below. other can follow the same

&& (depPortCr_Filter == 'any' || f.DeparturePortID == depPortCr_Filter).